# c# excel to SQL database import ( Must declare the scalar variable "@SICILNO".)

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error when I wrote the following code:

Must declare the scalar variable "@SICILNO".

**c# code :**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Lütfen Dosya Seçiniz";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = " Excel Dosyası (*.xls)|*.xls";
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "*.xls";
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        string dosya_yolu = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + dosya_yolu + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");
        OleDbCommand sorgu = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sayfa1$]", baglanti);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(sorgu);
        DataSet ds;
        DataTable Dt;


        ds = new DataSet();
            objAdapter1.Fill(ds);
            Dt = ds.Tables[0];

        baglanti.Open();
        OleDbDataReader drexcel = sorgu.ExecuteReader();


        SqlConnection baglan = new SqlConnection("Server=SBUKEN-NB; User ID=sa; Password=*******; Initial Catalog=PERSONEL");
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand();
        baglan.Open();


        DialogResult sonuc;
        sonuc = MessageBox.Show("Kayıtlar Veritabanına aktarılacak ! Onaylıyor musunuz ?","Onay Mesajı", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (sonuc == DialogResult.No)
        {
            baglan.Close();
        }
        if (sonuc == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = Dt.Rows[i];
                int columnCount = Dt.Columns.Count;
                string[] columns = new string[columnCount];
                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                {
                    columns[j] = row[j].ToString();
                }

                string sql = "INSERT INTO personel(SICILNO,ADI,SOYADI,KURUM,ISYERI,BOLUM,BIRIM,GOREVI,CINSIYET,";
                sql += " DTARIH,DYERI,MEDENIHALI,TCKIMLIKNO,EGITIM,ISEGIRIS,UCRETSIZIZIN,";
                sql += " UCRETI,SSKNO,OZELKOD,AGI,CIKISNEDENI,KIDEMYILI,YABANCIDIL, COCUKSAYISI,ASKERLIKDURUM,KANGURUBU,EHLIYET,ADRES,TELEFON,GSMNO,";
                sql += " ISTENCIKIS,MESLEKKODU,BABAADI)";
                sql += " VALUES (@SICILNO, @ADI, @SOYADI, @KURUM, @ISYERI,  @BOLUM, @BIRIM, @GOREVI,  @CINSIYET,  @DTARIH, @DYERI, @MEDENIHALI,  @TCKIMLIKNO, @EGITIM,  @ISEGIRIS,  @UCRETSIZIZIN, ";
                sql += " @UCRETI, @SSKNO, @OZELKOD,  @AGI, @CIKISNEDENI,  @KIDEMYILI, @YABACIDIL, @COCUKSAYISI,  @ASKERLIKDURUM,  @KANGURUBU,  @EHLIYET, @ADRES, @TELEFON, @GSMNO, @ISTENCIKIS, ";
                sql += " @MESLEKKODU, @BABAADI) ";


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, baglan);
                MessageBox.Show(sql.ToString());

                komut.Parameters.Add("@SICILNO", columns[0]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@ADI", columns[1]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@SOYADI", columns[2]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@KURUM", columns[3]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@ISYERI", columns[4]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@BOLUM", columns[5]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@BIRIM", columns[6]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@GOREVI", columns[7]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@CINSIYET", columns[8]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@DTARIH", columns[9]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@DYERI", columns[10]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@MEDENIHALI", columns[11]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@TCKIMLIKNO", columns[12]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@EGITIM", columns[13]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@ISEGIRIS", columns[14]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@UCRETSIZIZIN", columns[15]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@UCRETI", columns[16]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@SSKNO", columns[17]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@OZELKOD", columns[18]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@AGI", columns[19]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@CIKISNEDENI", columns[20]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@KIDEMYILI", columns[21]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@YABACIDIL", columns[22]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@COCUKSAYISI", columns[23]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@ASKERLIKDURUM", columns[24]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@KANGURUBU", columns[25]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@EHLIYET", columns[26]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@ADRES", columns[27]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@TELEFON", columns[28]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@GSMNO", columns[29]); 
                komut.Parameters.Add("@ISTENCIKIS", columns[30]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@MESLEKKODU", columns[31]);
                komut.Parameters.Add("@BABAADI", columns[32]); 

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                baglanti.Close();

            }
```

Comment: Better to hide your passwords from code you put on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters... you did not add the parameters to the command that that executed the query
try
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SICILNO", columns[0]);

Answer (score 1):

You use 2 instances of `SqlCommand`

`komut` and `cmd`.

You never add the `sql` string to `komut`, and never add the parameters to `cmd`...

So, you should choose which instance you wanna use !

**Solution**

remove

```
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand();
```

and replace `komut` by `cmd` in `komut.Parameters.Add(xxx)`